# Trying to run java code in Atom with script package, but it will error:file not found

Tags: java, atom-editor

I've been trying to test out my LeapYear code (basically tells you if a year is a leap year) however, whenever I use my <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> (hotkey for my script package to run) it will error:

**file not found: LeapYear.java**

It works perfectly fine with python, however, I am aware that java requires compiling and am a total CS noob, please help!

This is the code:

```java
public class LeapYear {
  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    int year = 28;
    if (year % 400 == 0) {
      System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");
      // return true;
      }

    else if ((year % 4 == 0) & (year % 100 != 0)) {
      System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");
      // return true;
      }

    else {
      System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
      // return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the error message:

```
error: file not found: LeapYear.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

I don't understand because the file name is `LeapYear.java`, surely it's able to locate itself having ran itself right?

Comment: it might be on the wrong path, it might be saved as LeapYear.java.txt, ... there are tons of possible reasons. The javac is trying to compile your file, but can't find it

Comment: Yeah, best try to find if you have saved the file with the right name (.java) and check whether you are in the right directory where file is saved when trying to run it. Run dir if you're using windows or ls if you're in linux or mac os to check which files are in that directory. Good luck learning Java :)

Comment: I had a quick check, it is definitely a .java file, however, because I'm trying to run it using Atom's (the text editor) "script" package (which is supposed to run code, works for python) it will appear with that error message.